# How to generate named patterns in Mathematica?

Tags: design-patterns, wolfram-mathematica

In principle, I want to use the following to generate a named pattern for later use:

```
In[1]:= Replace[var["x"],var[name_]:>Pattern[Apply[Symbol,name],_]]
```

I expected to see this result. A named pattern which I can use in subsequent rules:

```
Out[1]= x_
```

But instead, I got:

```
Out[1]= Pattern[Symbol @@ x,_]
```

The documentation says that Pattern[..] can only be used with a symbol as the first argument. Apply[Symbol, name] is not evaluated to return a symbol, so the Pattern[..] does not match.

Ho do I get a named pattern from some string name?

Comment: And your question is ?  And your intention is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `name_` matches the string `"x"` which results in `Apply[Symbol,"x"]` which returns an object with head `String`.  This is then passed to `Pattern` which returns what you see.  To get what you expect you have to pass a `Symbol` to `Pattern`.  Examine the various outputs you get with `FullForm[]`.

You can probably do this by changing the fragment:

```
Pattern[Apply[Symbol,name],_]]
```

to

```
Pattern[Evaluate[ToExpression[name],_]]
```

but this will only work if `ToExpression[name]` returns a `Symbol`.  I found that I had to force evaluation.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That produced exactely what I wanted. :)